# Use of semicolons in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I was under the impression semicolons became obsolete with ES6. However, I came across this today:

Doesn't work:

```
let i = 0

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(item => console.log(item))
```

Works:

```
let i = 0;

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].forEach(item => console.log(item))
```

Why is the semicolon necessary here, and when should I use them?

Comment: Where did you get this idea that semicolons became obsolete??!?

Comment: semicolons haven't become obsolete, automatic semicolon insertion has always been part of js. Starting a line with a square bracket is a case where adding a semi colon saves you from an asi error https://youtu.be/Qlr-FGbhKaI?t=5m58s

Comment: The [rules for automatic insertion of semicolons](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) is still basically the same in ES2015 as it always was

Comment: From here: [https://github.com/rse/es6-features](https://github.com/rse/es6-features#frequently-asked-questions-faq)

Comment: This isn't really any different in ES6 (with `let`) than in ES5 (with `var`).

Comment: @user5626500 That github link talks about tooling capabilities and style choices; nothing about changes to the rules behind semicolons.

Comment: an excellent explanation of the semicolon gotcha: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: An article on React.js best practices https://blog.risingstack.com/react-js-best-practices-for-2016/ says, "That's right, we do not use semicolons anymore."

Comment: I had the same question, and the way you asked it got four different topics addressed at once: 1. Didn't ECMA6 remove the semicolons.  Answer: (1a) No, they where always only a choice and still are. (1b) The ECMA6 adopts a semicolonless *style*  (2). So why did this happen (2a) technical explanation. (2b) use a linter to avoid.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Without the semicolon [1,2,3,4,5,6] will be evaluated as property access. Which is perfectly fine JS, I personally don't think that adding semicolons is such a big deal so I keep using them.

Comment: Let's call it "property access", not "index of an array". In `0[6]`, there is no array.

Comment: As an alternative to always using semicolons, linting tools can be used to catch these ambiguous scenarios for you, e.g. http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unexpected-multiline, this way you can keep the general rule of no semicolons, but add them in where necessary.